# Conditional title heading depending on output of code block R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I know this question has been asked before, but I'm still struggling to find an answer that works with my example.  Basically, I have this code block that reads the number of rows of a dataframe.  If there are any rows in the dataframe, it will output a table using `kable()`.  If there are zero rows, no table is output.

When the table IS output, I would like to have a title heading above the table (just bolded text, i.e. `"My Table"`).  When no table is output, I want no heading.  How can I accomplish this?  I've tried to use eval statements like `print_option` in the r setup block but no luck. Here's the stripped-down pseudo-code:

````
```{r warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=6}
    
    #Existing data frame my_df

   numRows <- nrow(my_df)

   if (numRows>0) {

       #Print table 
       my_df %>%
       arrange(my_field)%>%
       kable() %>%  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped","condensed", font_size = 12)

   }


```
````

Comment: Does your current solution work with, for example, the iris dataset?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your code does indeed work, but I've edited my question since I wasn't asking the right thing.  Sorry bout that!

Comment: What is the current output that you get using the code that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made minimal changes to implement your code with the iris dataset and it works as you would like it to.

### No rows (and no header)

````
```{r warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=6}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

#Existing data frame my_df
my_df <- iris[NULL, ]
numRows <- nrow(my_df)
```

`r  if (numRows > 0) {"## This is your heading written in markdown"}`

```{r warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=6}
if (numRows>0) {
  #Print table 
  my_df %>%
    arrange(Species) %>%
    kable() %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped","condensed", font_size = 12)
}
```
````

### With data (and table header)

````
```{r warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=6}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

#Existing data frame my_df
my_df <- iris[1:10, ]
numRows <- nrow(my_df)
```

`r  if (numRows > 0) {"## This is your heading written in markdown"}`

```{r warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=6}
if (numRows>0) {
  #Print table 
  my_df %>%
    arrange(Species) %>%
    kable() %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped","condensed", font_size = 12)
}
```
````

Comment: Gah, I made a mistake in asking my question.  What I meant was a table title - a heading - not a header.  Sorry!  Editing post now.

Comment: I updated the answer according to your edited question by injecting the following: `r  if (numRows > 0) {"## This is your heading written in markdown"}`

Comment: da11an, this works and I've accepted your answer, thank you.  But it still doesn't work with my slightly more complex real example, which I've re-posted here:  feel free to take a look and provide an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238775/rmarkdown-having-the-title-text-heading-before-a-table-be-conditional